# What loss function to use in Keras when metric is SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy/TopKCategoricalAccuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, metrics, loss-function

For multiclass classification problems, Keras and tf.keras have metrics like SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy and TopKCategoricalAccuracy. However, if one uses loss functions like SparseCategoricalCrossentropy or CategoricalCrossentropy, they cannot achieve the max values for these two metrics.

What is a good loss function to use when one wants to maximize SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy or TopKCategoricalAccuracy?

I understand that SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy is not differentiable, just like Accuracy. I am trying to find a function that can approximate the smooth loss function and yield a higher number for SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` or `CategoricalCrossentropy` aren't the right losses for your goals?

Comment: SparseCategoricalCrossentropy and CategoricalCrossentropy are the right metrics. But they are not loss functions. I am searching for a loss function that can yield the maximum SparceCategoricalCrossentropy or CategoricalCrossentropy value.

Comment: `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` and `CategoricalCrossentropy` are loss functions: https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#categoricalcrossentropy-class. Could there be a typo or misunderstanding somewhere?

Comment: You are right. There is a typo. What I meant to say is that I want to find a loss function that can maximize SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy and TopKCategoricalAccuracy. There is recent work on loss functions for top-k errors. But it is for SVM.https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/app/S06-51.pdf

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typo.

Comment: This is a multi-label task? That is you expect each input to produce 0-N positive labels?You might have some luck with binary cross entropy. Or, you can try implementing one of the losses from the paper you mentioned via Loss subclassing: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Loss

Comment: It is not a multi-label task. It is a multi-class task instead. Each input should be classified into one of N classes. Each input gets only 1 label.

Comment: Why can't `CategoricalCrossentropy` achieve the maximum values for the two metrics?

Comment: @rvinas From my experiments, the highest accuracy does not lead to highest topKaccuracy. Then I searched the net and found several papers on "smooth loss" functions for top-K classification. But they use SVM. So I am wondering if there is a loss function for deep learning as well. Do you think CategoricalCrossentropy would lead to highest TopKCategoricalAccuracy?

Comment: This is absolutely off-topic for this site

Comment: @NicolasGervais Why is it off topic for this site?

Answer (score 3):

**CrossEntropy** is not the best loss function when you deal with Top-k accuracy because cross-entropy may be prone to **overfitting on small datasets or noisy labels**.

As you have already pointed out, "smooth loss" functions are developed for top-k classification with SVM. To my knowledge, there is no a "off-the-shelf" loss function in Keras/TF that is best suited for top-k. However, I suggest you to try **Smooth Surrogate Loss** **(SSL)** presented in the [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.07595.pdf) and implemented in *Pytorch* to use with deep neural networks (see [Github](https://github.com/oval-group/smooth-topk)). It derives from multi-class SVMs as SSL creates a margin between the correct top-k predictions and the incorrect ones. The training time of SSL is comparatevely the same as in the case of cross-entropy thanking to a divide-and-conquer approach and the use of polynomials (see [implementation](https://github.com/oval-group/smooth-topk/tree/master/topk/polynomial)).